# tfenv not changing the Terraform version

Tags: terraform

```
$ tfenv version-name 
1.4.0

$ terraform --version
Terraform v1.2.7
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.48.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.4.3
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.5.7. You can update...
```

After I use tfenv the Terraform version does not change. What am I doing wrong? I also tried `tenv use v1.4.0`, but it does not help, the Terraform version stays the same.

```
$ tfenv use 1.4.0    
Switching default version to v1.4.0
Default version (when not overridden by .terraform-version or TFENV_TERRAFORM_VERSION) is now: 1.4.0
```

Comment: Could it be that you also have Terraform installed outside of tfenv, and this is the one that is being picked up in the PATH?

Comment: Yes, could be. I fixed it by reinstalling terraform and tfenv.

Comment: I think if you re-installed terraform and tfenv you will face the same problem. It should be 1 or the other. With tfenv you can have multiple versions & select whatever 1 you need, therefore re-installing terraform is not necessary. Some useful cmds: `tfenv --help` `tfenv list` `tfenv use latest`

Comment: A possible debugging tip for next time: if you run `which terraform` then you can see which executable matches that command name. If you are using `tfenv` then the result should be something under that tool's root directory. If it shows a file from elsewhere then that would confirm the hypothesis above that there's some other non-`tfenv`-managed `terraform` on your system that's taking priority.

Answer (score 1):

You have to uninstall any previously manually installed terraform and the generated Perform the following steps:

1. sudo rm /usr/bin/terraform
2. echo ‘export PATH=”$HOME/.tfenv/bin:$PATH”‘ >> ~/.bash_profile
3. sudo rm /usr/local/bin/tfenv
4. sudo rm /usr/local/bin/terraform
5. sudo ln -s ~/.tfenv/bin/* /usr/local/bin

This should remove the previously installed version of terraform and use tfenv to set the version of terraform.

Answer (score 0):

One way this could happen is by having multiple copies of Terraform installed.

tfenv expects to be the sole manager of Terraform, with no other copies installed outside of its control. When first using tfenv, you should uninstall any manually installed copies of Terraform, and then reinstall via tfenv.

If you don't do this, then it is possible that any manually installed Terraform could appear first in your PATH, which will give the appearance of `tfenv use` having no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. According to the [tfenv Homebrew page](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tfenv), the `terraform` and `tfenv` formulae conflict with each other. In my case, `terraform` was taking precedence over `tfenv`. Here's how I solved it using Homebrew on Mac. I'm not entirely sure that steps 1-3 were necessary - you may be able to get away with just step 4, but I wasn't able to test it to be sure.

1. Uninstall the `terraform` formula.

   ```
   brew uninstall terraform
   ```
2. Unlink `tfenv` temporarily so that `terraform` can be re-installed.

   ```
   brew unlink tfenv
   ```

   This removes the following files and directories (you can run `brew  unlink -n tfenv` to see a dry-run first):

   ```
   /opt/homebrew/bin/tfenv
   /opt/homebrew/lib/bashlog.sh
   /opt/homebrew/lib/helpers.sh
   /opt/homebrew/lib/tfenv-exec.sh
   /opt/homebrew/lib/tfenv-min-required.sh
   /opt/homebrew/lib/tfenv-version-file.sh
   /opt/homebrew/lib/tfenv-version-name.sh
   /opt/homebrew/share/hashicorp-keys.pgp
   ```
3. Reinstall the `terraform` formula.

   ```
   brew install terraform
   ```
4. Link `tfenv` again, and overwrite the conflicting `terraform` files: `brew link --overwrite tfenv`

   This overwrites the following link:

   ```
   /opt/homebrew/bin/terraform -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/terraform/1.5.7/bin/terraform
   ```

Now, running `terraform --version` gives me the same version as `tfenv version-name`.